# Why might someone be denied access to my website from a mobile hotspot?

Tags: ipv6

Full disclosure: I [asked this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72534/why-might-someone-be-denied-access-to-my-website-from-a-mobile-hotspot?noredirect=1#comment129757_72534) on "Network Engineering" and it was quickly closed as off-topic and the moderator sent me here.

Recently, I started self-hosting my academic webpage with a VPS. One of my students informed me that he could not load the webpage. We figured out that the problem was that he was connecting to the internet with a mobile hotspot. He switched his connection to his roomate's wifi and could connect to my page with no issues.

In short, my question is: Why might this happen?

My guess is that I didn't set-up ipv6 properly. My server runs arch linux. During the os install, I followed the [installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide#Network_configuration) and my `/etc/hosts` file is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost
127.0.1.1   myhostname.localdomain  myhostname
```

Here, I replaced `127.0.1.1` with my server's static ipv4 address. Should the ipv6 address be accounted for here? If so, how? Should I just duplicate the last line with the ipv4 address replaced by the ipv6 address?

Finally, this issue has made me realize that I do not have access to a device with an ipv6 address so I'm not sure how to test this issue myself. So, my followup question is: How can I test if my ipv6 connection is working properly without a device with an ipv6 address?

Comment: There's not enough information to even begin guessing; "could not load the webpage" can mean a million things. Has the student shared a screenshot of the issue they're having? (Is it a timeout? Is the browser unable to resolve the domain name? Is it having an HTTPS certificate problem? Is it receiving an actual error page from your web server?) Do you use Cloudflare or any other CDN frontend for the webpage? (I would test, but I assume that is not the same webpage as the one on your profile?)

Comment: One thing for sure though, your server's /etc/hosts file is **completely** irrelevant.

Comment: @user1686 Thanks for the reply! The student verbally communicated this over zoom a few weeks ago, so I forget the specific error message. I *think* the browser was unable to resolve the domain name. The url is: https://bfitz.xyz

Comment: I doubt its a ip4 vs ip6 problem if your site works on other client connections.  Have you tried confirming the webserver works via connecting to IP and port?  Then move on to DNS resolution troubleshooting.  FYI your site loads on my connection.  I suspect an issue with the students mobile hotspot in some way, they should talk to the ISP.

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect that IPv6 support is an issue, I suggest deleting the AAAA record in your DNS zone, leaving only the A record. Make a note of the current value first, so that you can put it back if it doesn't help.

This probably needs to be done with your DNS registrar, or hosting company. Editing your hosts file will not help.

It may take a few hours for DNS caches to expire and your student's device to see the DNS record updates.